# Using the TensorFlow Dataset api to import input/output pairs of variable lengths

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a collection of input/output pairs that I want to use as training examples for an RNN model.   So each input/output is a list of the same length consisting of integers id's.  So 3 training examples might look like

```
[
[[1,5,3,2],[22,5,3,8]],
[[2,3],[4,7]],
[[5,4,8,9,2,1,3],[32,4,7,4,5,21,33]]
]
```

My question is how to load this kind of data into a TensorFlow Dataset such that it can be fed to the model downstream?

I have experimented with the `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` method however it seems like all of the inputs and outputs must be of the same length in order to use this method.  However, as you can see from the above example, my inputs and outputs are of variable lengths.

Is the answer to pad the examples such that they are all the same length then use  `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`? If so is there a TensorFlow helper function that does this or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of generator and padded_batch concept of tf.data to overcome the variably sized input.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

data = [
[[1,5,3,2],[22,5,3,8]],
[[2,3],[4,7]],
[[5,4,8,9,2,1,3],[32,4,7,4,5,21,33]]
]

data_in = [x for x, y in data]
data_out = [y for x, y in data]

def gen_series():
    index_at = 0
    while True:
        yield data_in[index_at], data_out[index_at]
        index_at += 1
        if index_at >= len(data):
            index_at = 0

ds_series = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    gen_series,
    output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32),
    output_shapes = ((None, None)))

BATCH_SIZE = 2
ds_series_batch = ds_series.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=([None], [None]))

for input_tensor, output_tensor in ds_series_batch.take(2):
    print(input_tensor)
    print(output_tensor)
    print()
```

Padding will take place with maximum size of the input in the batch.

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 5 3 2]
 [2 3 0 0]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[22  5  3  8]
 [ 4  7  0  0]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=int32)

tf.Tensor(
[[5 4 8 9 2 1 3]
 [1 5 3 2 0 0 0]], shape=(2, 7), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[32  4  7  4  5 21 33]
 [22  5  3  8  0  0  0]], shape=(2, 7), dtype=int32)
```